# Show $f$ is Riemann integrable on $R$.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $R=[a_1,b_1]\times\cdots\times[a_n,b_n]\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Let $f:R\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuous function. I want to show that $f$ is Riemann integrable on $R$. I know that Riemann integrable means the upper integral equals the lower integral. But how can I show that?

Comment: What have you tried?  Are there values of $n$ for which you already know this is true (for example, $n=1$)?  Does that give you any hints for how to attack $n=2$ and subsequently?

Comment: @EricTowers I know this is true when $n=1.$ Do you mean I should use induction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some suggestions as I don't want to give the whole game away:

You will probably want to use the fact that a continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous. This is helpful as you can fix an $\varepsilon$ and then chose a $\delta$ such that on cubes with sides of length $\delta$ your function doesn't vary by more than $\varepsilon$. You can then upper bound $f$ by the supremum of $f$ on each of these cubes. Similarly you can lower bound $f$. You should find that, since $\varepsilon$ was arbitrary, you can Make the upper and lower bound arbitrarily close to one another.

Comment: I agree with you that I should use the fact that continuous on a compact set implies uniformly continuous. But I don't see very clearly why this is helpful and how to use it in the proof.

Comment: Have you seen the proof for this in the $n=1$ case? You can use similar ideas as in that

Comment: I just find one proof for this when $n=1.$ I will look through it.

Comment: I hope the proof you found helped! :)